# Mandrill or Mailchimp. Config tracking email open, click link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, mailchimp, mandrill

When I use mandrill or mailchimp, how could I track user open email and when they click to link in that email? Is mandrill and mailchimp ,... support it, I want to get that info and save into my database INstead of viewing it in mandrill or mailchimp page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mandrill does this for you. All you need to do is add a webhook and build an api endpoint for that. Mandrill will send you the data you need in "real time".

Here are the docs on how to setup the webhook; https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205583217-Introduction-to-Webhooks